# Fixtures with polymorphic association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, fixtures, rolify

I'm trying to implement the Rolify gem but have trouble adding fixtures with a scope for it. The last line of the (model) test below fails because currently the moderator role seems to be given to `@user` globally instead of only for organization one. The fixtures below aren't using `resource_id` and `resource_type`, which are mentioned in the [gem documentation](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Rolify-with-Rails-fixtures) for fixtures, but I'm not sure how to use them. *How should I set the scope for the moderator role to only organization one?*

---

roles.yml

```
moderator:
  id: 1
  resource: one (Organization)
```

users.yml

```
one:
  email: example@example.com
  roles: moderator, organizations(:one)           # I was hoping this would set the scope of the role to organization one but it isn't (seems to set the role globally).
```

test.rb

```
def setup
  @moderator_role = roles(:moderator)
  @organization1  = organizations(:one)
  @organization2  = organizations(:two)
  @user           = users(:one)
end

test "should be moderator if fixtures correct" do 
  assert_equal @user.has_role?('moderator'), true
  assert_equal @user.has_role?(:moderator, @organization1), true
  assert_equal @user.has_role?(:moderator, @organization2), false       # This line fails
end
```

---

**Update:** I also tried the code below. But still the test fails.

roles.yml

```
moderator:
  name: :moderator
  resource: one (Organization)
```

users.yml

```
one:
  organization: one
  roles: moderator, organizations(:one)
```

organizations.yml

```
one:
  name: "Company A"
```

test.rb

```
def setup
  @moderator_role = roles(:moderator)
  @organization1  = organizations(:one)
  @organization2  = organizations(:two)
  @user           = users(:one)
end

test "should be moderator if fixtures correct" do 
  assert_equal @user.has_role?('moderator'), true                      # This line fails
  assert_equal @user.has_role?(:moderator, @organization1), true       # This line also fails
  assert_equal @user.has_role?(:moderator, @organization2), false
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that with the code in the update, the test does pass if I run it as a users controller test or integration test, instead of as a model test. So I guess I was just running it as the wrong type of test.