# undefined method error on seeding array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding, rolify

I'm implementing a gem called Rolify. I've successfully created a controller and model method to assign a moderator role to users. However, I'm having trouble seeding and testing. For testing I have posted a [seperate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31120751/4499505).

The idea for seeding is to first create the role in the Role table. Then to take 30 random organizations and for each organization 2 random users, and assign these 2 users a moderator role for that organization. At the end of my seeds file I added:

```
moderator = Role.create!(:moderator => "moderator") 

organizations = Organization.take(30)
organizations.each do |org|
  2.times do |n|
    user = User.where(usertype: 1).take(1)
    user.add_role :moderator, org
  end
end
```

The error I get on seeding of creation of the role in the Role table:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'moderator' for Role.
```

The error I get on seeding of the second part:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'add_role' for #<Array:0x0000000581f268>
```

`Add_role` is a method from rolify and is also used in my controller methods, where it *does* work.

Any idea what could be causing this seeding problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `moderator` as one of the columns in your db's `roles` table.

For second error, line:

```
user = User.where(usertype: 1).take(1)
```

is creating an array object of user(s), not the user. Try changing it to:

```
user = User.where(usertype: 1).first
```

Comment: You can omit the `take(1)` when doing `first`

Comment: @PiotrKruczek : Yes, completely forgot to remove it. thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But I was wondering: 1) In development the moderator role works. So I shouldn't need to add any columns just for seeding. Therefore, I'm thinking perhaps the rolify gem doesnt require the role to be defined this way, i.e., I can just leave out the first part of the seeds code. 2) About the `.first`. I would like to each time take a random user and wouldn't `.first` cause it to be the same user each time, instead of a random user? P.S. Seed does indeed work if I use `.first` but because of the reason mentioned I have doubts if I should do it this way?

Comment: `first` here acts the same as `take` without parameters. In the source code, there's a `.to_a` called on returned object(s) if there is any parameter passed (even `1`). None of those methods meddle in order of your elements, just take the first one.

Comment: @Nick : For `moderator`, paste your migration for `roles` table, or schema of your `roles` table from your sql console. Second: `take(1)` will create an array of one user object, instead use `first`, it will work the same way.

Comment: Thanks Surya. It works I didn't need first line of seeds. And to get a random user, I used: `user = User.offset(rand(User.where(usertype: 1).count)).first`